# JMeter - IBM MQ - Connections Issue

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, ibm-mq

We have been doing performance testing of an application that uses IBM MQ. Through JMeter we are injecting the payload via a JMS Publisher. However, when running the test it can be observed that the connections from the JMeter threads are not being released. This effects the ability to reach the throughput and test failure due to the accumulation of threads. Is there a better alternative than using the JMS Publisher? Or is there setting there that needs to be enabled in order to release the connection once the request has been sent?

[image]

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-tutorial - Is this the best practice to implement testing IBM MQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve? JMeter implements [Object Pool Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) so each JMeter thread (virtual user) creates its own JMS connection and on subsequent iterations of the JMS Publisher sampler the `Publisher` object is being returned from the pool rather than created from zero.

If this is not something you want (or not how your JMS application acts) and you would like to close the connection after posting a message to queue/topic you can achieve it quite easily using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following [Groovy code:](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

```
def publisher = sampler.publisher
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.client.ClientPool.removeClient(publisher)
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(publisher, null)
sampler.publisher = null
```

Comment: Whilst running a performance test the IBM-MQ admin identified that the JMeter connections to the queue were increasing over time and affecting the performance of IBM-MQ in turn. We are looking to close the connection once a message has been posted to the queue to avoid MQ getting thrashed with unnecessary/increasing connections.

Comment: To provide more clarity, the scenario contains steady state and spikes. During the steady state the connections seems to stay stable. However, during a soak test after each spike the number of connections increase, cumulatively. From the description above it doesn't sound like it should do that. I will try the code above and see how we get on. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't matter what "we are looking to", you need to simulate the real usage of the IBMMQ broker by upstream application/process and do exactly what the application/process does. If in reality the connection gets closed right after sending the message - you can copy and paste the code. However establishing a connection is kind of "expensive" process so in the majority of cases producers implement Connection Pool on their side

Comment: Agreed - and that is what MQ is doing, closing the connection. But our tests are not emulating that.

Comment: MQ client-side does not close connections.  They will timeout after whatever your system's default TCP timeout value is set to but otherwise, the application should be explicitly closing the connection (aka disconnect).

Comment: Thanks Roger. I think we found the issue as to why the number of connections are accumulating. We had three nested JMS Publisher objects in one thread group. Because we are emulating a spike scenario over 24 hours. And Roger's comment further confirms why the connections have been accumulating. We implemented the above code and it looks to be working better now. Thank you guys!